# Jquery modification to add 1 and save the number in a txt file on every click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following click function for a purpose. What can I add so it will add 1 in a txt file when it is clicked? Like a counter on how many times it was clicked.

Thank you

```
$("#clearme").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // i have some stuff here
});
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain JavaScript doesn't have access to the file system, so it shouldn't be able to write to files, let alone *create* files. It could possibly interface with a server-side script to do the same, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access or edit files from the front-end. You'll need PHP or something. You can save it in a variable and pass it and process it with ajax. Something like this, untested:

```
var num = 0;
$button.click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'bla.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { num: ++num }
        //...
    });
});
```

And in PHP:

```
$num = $_POST['num'];
// Add to file stuff
```

Comment: Well, that's basically it, I mean the only thing is the PHP append to file stuff.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to modify the text file on the server. Send a ajax request every time the click event happens.

```
$("#clearme").click(function(e) {
    $.post("url")
    e.preventDefault();
    // i have some stuff here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Text file where?  On the server or the client machine?

If you're aiming for the client machine, javascript and jquery alone aren't going to work.  There are security measures to prevent this so that would be hackers don't drop trojans on our machines every time we visit a website.

That leaves the server.

Accomplishing this depends entirely on the server side language/framework you are using (i.e. PHP, JSP, .NET).

You didn't post the reason behind needing to do this, so I'll offer the option of writing the value to a cookie instead of a file, but since you haven't told us more about what you're up to, this might not be a viable solution.